# MySQL Count totals by year and month and Calcul Cumulative count

Tags: mysql, count

I need help for optimize my SQL request.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id,resgier_date,action
1,'2011-01-01 04:28:21','signup'
2,'2011-01-05 04:28:21','signup'
3,'2011-02-02 04:28:21','signup'
```

How do I select and group these so the output is:

```
year,month,total,cumulative_sum
2011,1,2,2
2011,2,1,3
```

I would like, with one request, add, one column with cumulative of count(id).

I try with a request like that :

```
SELECT YEAR(REGISTER_DATE),
     count( * ),
     @running_total := @running_total + count( * ) AS cumulative_sum
FROM MYTABLE t
     JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
GROUP BY YEAR(REGISTER_DATE)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

With no success

Thank(s for you help

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT year, 
       month, 
       total, 
       @rt := @rt + total cumulative_sum
  FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(register_date) year,
               MONTH(register_date) month,
               COUNT(*) total
          FROM mytable
          GROUP BY YEAR(register_date), MONTH(register_date)
          LIMIT 0, 30
       ) n, (SELECT @rt := 0) r
```

Output

```
| YEAR | MONTH | TOTAL | CUMULATIVE_SUM |
-----------------------------------------
| 2011 |     1 |     2 |              2 |
| 2011 |     2 |     1 |              3 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fb91/6)**